# SSIS 2019 acting differently than 2012 with respect to writing numeric data to .csv flat files

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, numeric, flat-file, sql-server-2019

When running an SSIS package on a 2019 server, the output of numeric fields that are 0 are now being written as blanks. When it was running on a 2012 server, it was writing a 0.

The initial data is coming from Postgres, but from all what I can tell, the value is a 0, not a null. Then when we run the code in 2012 mode on a 2012 server, there are no issues. When we run the same code in 2012 mode or 2019 mode on a 2019 server, we get a blank being written out.

Comment: Something is therefore different. We don't know what, but *something* is. You'll need to dig deeper here.

Comment: Compare your versions of the Postgres drivers

Comment: The driver versions are 11.00.x on both the 2021 and 2019 boxes for Postgres. I think the issue is that the SQL 2019 is the "different" part from 2012 and is causing the issues. As I look at data in the data viewer during execution, I see the 0s coming from Postgres, but SSIS is just not writing them that way.

Comment: Check the flat file writer to see how 0's and nulls are handled.

Answer (score 0):

A little late for this, maybe try to execute it from a lower version like 2016, then save it, then try to run the package again with 2019.